# Implement support library in QT

Tags: android, qt, android-studio

I need to run 
this code:

> getSupportActionBar().hide();

Which uses this library:

> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

I can run this code easily on `Android studio`, But actually I need to run this on `QT Android`, I added the `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` to my dependenices, to add the needed libaray in QT,
But when I run the

> getSupportActionBar().hide();

I get no result, but lots of error!!!
Is it possible to run all java code in QT?

Comment: Yes it is possible. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html for an example that shows android notifications from Qt

Comment: @ Felix, Yes and I tried that before, but It seems some are not working !

Comment: Most likely a usage error. The API itself is just a convenient wrapper around the JNI. Read through all the class documentations and try debugging to pin point the problem. Try to find out what the errors mean. Are they compile, link, cpp runtime or java runtime errors etc...

Comment: @Felix I got no error, It's just not working, while in Android studio working properly!

Comment: In that case, edit your post to add some more code! Show us how you invoke those methods from C++ etc.